# ErrorHandler for resolving multiple exceptions in a single place?

Tags: java, exception, design-patterns

I have a `ServiceExecutor` and runs a long routine (webervices calls, DB updates, user updates etc). As these routines can cause several errors, I'd like to catch lots of them in one single place. Therefore I wrapped it with trycatch. But each exception should get a custom error handling, so will have 5-10 lines of code to resolve the error.

Problem: my `runLongRoutine()` gets too big, so I somehow have to factor the error handling out. But I do not want to rethrow  these exeptions as any class using `runLongRoutine()` should not care about errors, and must not even know that errors might occure.

How could I adapt the error handling here? Is there a design pattern I could chose?

```
class ServiceExecutor {
    void runLongRoutine() {
        try {
            several(param1);
            calls();
            to(param2);
            different(param3, param1);
            methods();
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            //5-10 lines of code
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //5-10 lines of code
        } catch (NetworkException e) {
            //5-10 lines of code
        }
        //to be continued
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily factor out the exception handling (for each type of exception) and/or the actual code into separate private methods, e.g.

```
class ServiceExecutor {
    void runLongRoutine() {
        try {
            runLongRoutine0();
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            //5-10 lines of code
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //5-10 lines of code
        } catch (NetworkException e) {
            //5-10 lines of code
        }
        //to be continued
    }

    private void runLongRoutine0() throws CustomException, IOException, NetworkException {
        several(param1);
        calls();
        to(param2);
        different(param3, param1);
        methods();
    }
}
```

or

```
class ServiceExecutor {
    void runLongRoutine() {
        try {
            several(param1);
            calls();
            to(param2);
            different(param3, param1);
            methods();
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            handleCustomException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            handleIOException(e);
        } catch (NetworkException e) {
            handleNetworkException(e);
        }
        //to be continued
    }

    private void handleCustomException(CustomException e) { ... }
    private void handleIOException(IOException e) { ... }
    private void handleNetworkException(NetworkException e) { ... }
}
```

or even a combination of both approaches if really necessary.

Comment: Yes that might be an option. Though, I'd prefer to somehow take the whole try-catch stuff error handling *out* of the `ServiceExecutor` somehow...

Comment: I guess that's not possible, some code needs to handle the exceptions. And if it's neither your caller, nor the methods you call, then there is not much choice left.

Comment: Would you think an anonymous inner class as ErrorHandler is a good practice? @see http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/exception-handling-templates.html

Comment: If you can reuse the exception handling code for other code as well, that might be an nice option. If not, I would say it adds a lot of boiler plate for little benefit.

Comment: OK it's probably best to stick to your 2nd approach here.

Answer (score 1):

The [Chain-of-responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)  pattern may of interest to you. Another easy to implement way is to catch any exception and to us a `Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Handler>` which maps exception types to exception handlers. If you can't find any use a default handler or just rethrow it.

```
try {
    // some code
} catch (Throwable e) {
    ExceptionHandler handler = handlers.get(e.getClass());
    if (handler != null) handler.handle(e);
    else DEFAULT_HANDLER.handle(e);
}
// to be continued
```

Comment: Be careful, there are often subclasses of exceptions that are actually thrown (i.e., FileNotFoundException which inherits from IOException), so a simple map lookup for `e.getClass()` is not enough.

Comment: Also catching Throwable is usually not advisable, as you should normally not catch RuntimeExceptions and especially Errors (such as OutOfMemoryError). Make sure to appropriately rethrow these exception types, or (in Java 7) use multi-catch: `catch (CustomException | IOException | NetworkException e)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try AOP.
You can write an aspect that handles the exception around this method.

Comment: I doubt letting spring rewrite the bytecode of my class is a good solution on refactoring exception handling.

Comment: It seems to me that AOP is a better fit for cases where you want to add the same code in multiple places, not just some specific code for one place.